# Facebook prepends 'Facebook.com' to og:url, ignores open graph tags

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I have a simple application with 'game' and 'article' pages that users can share via the Facebook 'like' button. No cookies, no sessions, no logins. My open graph tags are rendered on the page as such:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Sample title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://foo.com/articles/article-one-title/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://cdn.com/articles/image.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Foo" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Foo description" />
```

When I lint the page with Facebook's debug tool, it shows no errors and the scraped page also displays the above tags.

When I 'like' the page, however, the url that appears is "http://www.facebook.com/articles/article-one-title/", and the remaining og tags are ignored.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you entered a partial URL in your Like button.

```
/articles/article-one-title/
```

instead of

```
http://foo.com/articles/article-one-title/
```

Your code should be something like `<fb:like href="http://foo.com/articles/article-one-title/" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true"></fb:like>`

not

`<fb:like href="/articles/article-one-title/" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true"></fb:like>`

Comment: Ah, how silly. My og tags were absolute but the actual fb code was not. Thanks for your reply.